# How to use already Trained model to run on esemble of inputs in parallel?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, parallel-processing

I have a PyTorch model trained for a specific task, which I load using `model.load_state_dict(torch.load('PATH_TO_SAVE_MODEL.pth'))`. I want to use this model to predict outputs for around 100,000 different sets of inputs.

Is there a way to parallelize this prediction process to make it more efficient?

Currently, I am running the model on each input set separately and saving the predicted outputs, but this process is time-consuming.

EDIT: This model is an autoencoder model used for Computational Fluid Dynamics. It uses convolutional transpose layers. It takes flow input parameters like viscosity, and density and outputs an image of the flow field at the steady-state solution.

Comment: Don't know what your model is, what the rest of your code does or what your input looks like. But if it is some kind of neural network that accepts batches of input, then the obvious solution that comes to mind would be to gather as many of your input data into a single batch, process it and then gather another batch

Comment: This model is an autoencoder model used for Computational Fluid Dynamics. It takes flow input parameters like viscosity, and density and outputs an image of the flow field at the steady-state solution.

Comment: Sounds like it should be able to accept a batch of inputs. Probably something you do during training already

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller for the replies. I already tried it, but the process of storing the data (I mean writing the data files) is time-consuming and was hoping there is a way to predict outputs simultaneously as well as write those files in parallel.